# How can I replace part of string by position to the end of the string?

Tags: c#

If i have a string

```
"https://test.local.com/{version}/123456
```

I want to replace {version}/123456 with v50.0

How can i do that ?

Comment: Is the value `/123456` a constant or varies? Is the value `/123456` always stays in the last of the string?

Comment: I will always get a response in string format as "https://test.local.com/{version}/123456 and yes the 123456 could vary , but i dont care. I just want to replace starting from {version} to the end with v50.o so i will end up with "https://test.local.com/v50.0

Comment: If `https://test.local.com` be always same?

Comment: no it wont . I just want to grab the start pos of {version} and the end pos as the end of the string and replace that part thats all ,

Comment: You just gave yourself the answer how to do that. [`String.IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-6.0#system-string-indexof(system-string-system-int32-system-int32)) will be of help.

Comment: For that we need to get a reference position. Shall `https://test.local.com` have a pattern? e.g shall the URL `https://test.local.com` have something constant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the possible solution.

```
string url = "https://test.local.com/{version}/123456";
int versionIndex = url.IndexOf("{version}");
string output = url;
if(versionIndex >= 0)
{
 output = url.Substring(0,versionIndex) + "v50.0";
}
```

Comment: perfect works great